# Can someone help verify the first part of my solution for this DDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this delayed differential equation that I saw in a paper I'm studying
$$y′(t)=ay(t)−ay(t−\tau)$$
with $a$ as a positive constant, $y(t−\tau)=0$ for $t<\tau$ and the initial condition as $y(0)=y_0$. (I posted about this a couple of days ago and was making a terrible mistake so I deleted that one. I'm doing it again now, but I compare my solution to the one that someone else got and it's slightly different, even though I think my working is correct mostly? I can't see their working so I'm not sure where/if I'm going wrong, so I just wanted to confirm if I'm making a mistake or not.)

I'll outline my working below:

On $[0,\tau]$ we have
$$y′(t)−ay(t)=0$$
which gives us
$$y(t)=y_0e^{at}$$
if we use an integrating factor of $e^{−at}$.

For $[\tau,2\tau]$:
$$y′(t)−ay(t)=−ay_0e^{a(t-\tau)}$$

which gives me $$y(t) = y_0e^{at}[1-ae^{-a\tau}(t-\tau)]$$

Then, for $t \in [2\tau, 3\tau]$, I can just continue using the method of steps, but I get a super long expression that does not,,, particularly seem like it would be very generalizable, so I'm not sure if I can get a closed form solution or not (also why I think I might be making a mistake).

(Edit: Adding it here anyway)

For $t \in [2\tau, 3\tau]$:

$$y(t) = y_0 e^{at}\bigg[1-at+2a\tau +
ae^{-a\tau}\bigg(a\bigg(\frac{t^2}{2} - 2\tau\bigg) + \tau - 2\tau^2\bigg) \bigg]$$

Could someone please confirm if I got the first bits that I've written up there correct though? I'd appreciate it a lot, as I do tend to make many many basic errors sometimes.

**EDIT 2:**

Got the answer by continuing to use the method of steps and changing how I wrote my solution for $t \in [2\tau, 3\tau]$ to
$$y(t) = y_0\bigg[e^{at}-a(t-\tau)e^{a(t-\tau)} + \frac{a^2}{2}(t-2\tau)^2e^{a(t-2\tau)}\bigg]$$ instead of what it was before, which gave me a much nicer way to look at it.

Then I generalized this to pretty much the exact thing user DinosaurEgg wrote below except I realized it after looking at the answers fully once I was done lol. But yeah, so I get the sum

$$y(t) = y_0 \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-a)^k}{k!} (t-k\tau)^ke^{a(t-k\tau)}$$ which is again, the exact same as the answer below.

Thanks for all the help though! I do appreciate it! :)

Comment: Your methodology is correct but is not applicable in general due to its complexity. In general, we do not solve analytically DDEs but study the properties of the solutions without computing them directly.

Comment: In general, DDEs don't have explicit solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to get at can be expressed very concisely by applying a Laplace transform to the DDE above to obtain

$$Y(s)=\frac{y_0}{s-a+ae^{-s\tau}}$$

where we denote $Y(s)=\int_0^\infty y(t)e^{-st}dt$. To obtain the expansion you have above just expand the denominator around $\tau=\infty$ which can be achieved by expanding in powers of $e^{-s\tau}$. This yields

$$Y(s)=\frac{y_0}{s-a}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{a}{s-a}\right)^ne^{-ns\tau}$$

Formally inverting the Laplace transform term by term now yields the desired result

$$y(t)=y_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-a)^n}{n!}\theta(t-n\tau)(t-n\tau)^ne^{a(t-n\tau)}$$

with $\theta(x)$ the Heaviside step function. Unpacking the formula we derived a little further, we see the solution is different for every interval $(m\tau,(m+1)\tau)~,~ m\in\mathbb{N}$ and is given by

$$y_m(t)=\sum_{n=0}^m\frac{(-a)^n}{n!}(t-n\tau)^ne^{a(t-n\tau)}~~,~~t\in \left(m\tau, (m+1)\tau\right)$$

and this is probably the closest one can get to a closed form expression. Note that continuity is automatically satisfied here, because

$$y_{m+1}(t)-y_m(t)\Big|_{t=(m+1)\tau}=\frac{(-a)^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}(t-(m+1)\tau)^{m+1}e^{a(t-(m+1)\tau)}\Big|_{t=(m+1)\tau}=0$$

With this you can easily verify that your solutions in $(0,2\tau)$ are correct.

Comment: Ah yess thank youu! So I usually avoided Laplace transforms because I get to the first expression but then I'm not sure how to invert it, and hence why I usually avoided it. Also, so the paper I'm working with has a as a constant, but also later works with a as a function of t, so a Laplace transform wouldn't work with that, while I believe the method of steps would. Small question though. Is your second expression a Taylor series expansion?

Comment: Okay so I continued doing what I was doing as well and I got the exact same solution as you which is super cool (for a constant a, going to see what I get for a time dependent a now).

Comment: It is a Taylor expansion indeed, but in the awkward variable$ \frac{e^{-s\tau}}{s-a}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your formulas are correct, I think.  But the argument *does* generalize.

Suppose $p_k(t)$ is a polynomial in $t$ such that $$y(t)=y_0p_k(t-k\tau)e^{a(t-k\tau)}$$ on $t\in[k\tau,(k+1)\tau]$.

Then \begin{align*}
y_0p_k'(t-k\tau)e^{a(t-k\tau)}&=y_0p_k'(t-k\tau)e^{a(t-k\tau)}+y_0ap_k(t-k\tau)e^{a(t-k\tau)}-y_0ap_k(t-k\tau)e^{a(t-k\tau)} \\
&=y'(t)-ay(t) \\
&=-ay(t-\tau) \\
&=-y_0ap_{k-1}((t-\tau)-(k-1)\tau)e^{a(t-\tau-(k-1)\tau)} \\
&=-y_0ap_{k-1}(t-k\tau)e^{a(t-k\tau)}
\end{align*}  Canceling, we find that $p_k'=-ap_{k-1}$.

Moreover, to ensure continuity, we must have $$p_{k-1}(\tau)e^{a\tau}=y(k\tau)=p_k(0)$$  Thus $$p_k(t)=e^{a\tau}p_{k-1}(\tau)-a\int_0^t{p_{k-1}(s)\,ds}$$

Putting it all together, we obtain a simple recurrence for the $\{p_k\}_k$: \begin{align*}
p_k(t)&=e^{a\tau}p_{k-1}(\tau)-a\int_0^t{p_{k-1}(s)\,ds} \\
p_0(t)&=1
\end{align*}

In particular, the recurrence isn't too bad, when expressed in coefficients: if $p_k(t)=\sum_j{c_{k,j}t^j}$, then $$c_{k,j}=\begin{cases}
-\frac{a}{j}c_{k-1,j-1} & j>0 \\
e^{a\tau}\sum_l{c_{k-1,l}\tau^l} & j=0 \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ahh thank you, this is interesting. So I'm going to try doing this again (possibly with a different way to write the terms that I got) so that I can get to this/a similar conclusion myself, but it's good to know that a closed form solution does exist, so thank you!